# How to sent content view with androidx for databinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

Unfortunately, I can't set the content view for my Android app. I don't know how this is done for the migration to androidx.

Here is the following code snippet not working for me:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityPostListBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_post_list)
        binding.postList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        viewModel = PostListViewModel(applicationContext)
        viewModel.errorMessage.observe(this, Observer {
            errorMessage -> if(errorMessage != null) showError(errorMessage) else hideError()
        })
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    }
```

How do you implement it the right way? 
This line for androidx:

binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_post_list)

Comment: Try 
`binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(parent.context,R.layout.activity_post_list)`

Comment: not working for me. Still everything red: ```binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(parent.applicationContext, R.layout.activity_post_list)```

Comment: try  Sync project with Gradle files. By the way, do you get any error message

Comment: project has been already synced

Comment: have you already enabled `dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }` in your app.gradle file? 
and did you `import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil` in the activity?

Comment: Type parameter bound for T in fun <T : ViewDataBinding!> setContentView(activity: Activity, layoutId: Int): T!
 is not satisfied: inferred type ActivityPostListBinding! is not a subtype of ViewDataBinding!

Comment: import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil - yes I did

Comment: could you maybe lift out the `lateinit` declaration and try inside the `onCreate` method

`var binding : ActivityHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_post_list)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206884/discussion-between-johannes-n-and-bwappsandmore).